# Can anybody explain me why we don't have classes in material ui with reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui

I am using material ui with react.js (material-ui.com) and trying to overwrite material-ui's default styles, but as after compilation all styles become inline, my styles are always overwrites.
As I understand I have two options.
1. write my styles inline too
2. write with !important's.

Is there any way to make components styles with classes?

Comment: have you seen the documentation of components on http://material-ui.com almost all of them have ways to override styles or do you want other ways to override the style?

Comment: They offer to overwrite by inline style. What I need, is to overwrite within classes. So I need to use !important's because inline styles overwrite classes. It is not a good idea.